# Override Plugin Script Fucnction in Wordpress

Tags: plugins, php, functions, javascript

I don't know how to remove a specific function from a plugin.

My plugin is Photo-gallery.

I want to remove this function:

```
function spider_createpopup(url, current_view, width, height, duration, description, lifetime, lightbox_ctrl_btn_pos){
...
}
```

from the file `\wp-content\plugins\photo-gallery\js\bwg_gallery_box.js`

I've tried many things but nothing worked. Last thing i tried in my function.php is :

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_deregister_script2', 100);


function wp_deregister_script2( ) {
  _wp_scripts_maybe_doing_it_wrong( bwg_gallery_box , bwg_gallery_box );

    wp_scripts()->remove( bwg_gallery_box );
}
```

But it's removing more than just `spider_createpopup()`

How can I do that?

Edit: I want to remove this function in some conditions, for example if the user in not logged in, so he can't use all the fonctionality of the plugin to see more pictures in the page.

Comment: You're calling maybe_doing_it_wrong on yourself ??

Comment: No, you can't just remove a single function from a script from WordPress: you can only load the whole script. (And [some tricks aside](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16498247/243245) you can't undeclare a function either.) Your best bet is going to be to edit that script, which probably means forking the plugin and giving it a different name so that automatic updates don't put the function back.

Comment: Why do you need to remove the function anyway? Can't you just ignore it?